# Saving a textfile into sql and sending it to FTP server

Tags: c#, sql, ftp

I have created a textfile programmatically and I saved it into a folder and now I need to save it into a table inside a database(I have already created the table)and after that fill a checkbox with those textfiles and send them to an FTP server. 
Is that possible? If so how can I start doing it/what should I do?
Here is the code for creating the textfile and the code to the create the table. If you have any question about the code feel free to ask.

```
var numfatura = _transaction.TransDocument + _transaction.TransSerial + _transaction.TransDocNumber;

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\HP8200\\Desktop\\Faturas Teste\\" +numfatura + ".txt"))
        {
            string numcont = _transaction.PartyFederalTaxID;
            double numenc = _transaction.BillToPartyID;
            DateTime data = _transaction.CreateDate;
            double valor = _transaction.TotalAmount;
            int zona = transaction.UnloadPlaceAddress.AddressID;
            string zona2 = transaction.UnloadPlaceAddress.AddressLine2;
            double quantidade = transaction.Details.Count;
            string bonus = "0";
            string valorStr = valor.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            writer.WriteLine($"{numcont};{numenc};{numfatura};{data:dd/MM/yyyy};{valorStr};{zona};");
            foreach (ItemTransactionDetail detail in transaction.Details)
            {
                var item = MyApp.DSOCache.ItemProvider.GetItem(detail.ItemID, MyApp.SystemSettings.BaseCurrency);
                double taxRate = MyApp.DSOCache.TaxesProvider.GetTaxRateFromTaxableGroupID(detail.TaxableGroupID, "PRT", "CON");
                string barcode = item.BarCode;
                var preconet = detail.TaxIncludedPrice;
                var precoantesdisc = detail.UnitPrice;
                string preconetStr = preconet.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                string precoantesdiscStr = precoantesdisc.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                writer.WriteLine($"{barcode};{taxRate};{precoantesdiscStr};{preconetStr};{quantidade};{bonus}");
            }

        } // create the text file
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data source = 2c4138928627\Sage ; Database=ARMINDOData ; User Id=sa ; Password=sage2008+");
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("IF OBJECT_ID('UXFaturas', 'U') IS NULL CREATE TABLE UXFaturas(Faturas char(250));", conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO UXFaturas(Faturas) VALUES (*.txt)", conn);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("saved"); // create the table and insert the textfile
```

Comment: I do not see how the SQL, checkbox and FTP question parts relate to each other. One question at a time only, please! This is not a code writing service.

Comment: Ok, sorry. First I need to save the textfile into the SQL. Then fill a checbox with the data saved on the SQL and then send the checked files into a FTP server.

Comment: You can write a stored procedure that takes in your file name and the content's inside it and save it into a table.

Comment: @HariGovind I tought on that but I had no clue on how to do it

Comment: Since you are already looping through your input data to create the file, why not add database records inside the same loop?

Comment: I don't know why you deleted your other question but you're posting your `sa` password all over the internet, if this is not your own little play or develop database but an actual database that someone cares about **you need to change this password now**. It's too late to start deleting posts with this password now as it is all over the place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a stored procedure that takes in two parameters **fileName** and **fileContent** and then store it inside your **UXFaturas table**.

```
CREATE PROC USP_InsertFile(@fileName nvarchar(200),@fileContent nvarchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO UXFaturas VALUES(@fileName,@fileContent)
END
```

Here i am assuming that you **UXFaturas table** only has two columns.

Now you can simple call this stored procedure from your C# ADO code and pass in the right parameters.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data source = 2c4138928627\Sage ; Database=ARMINDOData ; User Id=sa ; Password=sage2008+"))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                command.Connection = conn;

                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = "USP_InsertFile";

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileName",fileName);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileContent",fileContent);

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Comment: I'll try it and soon i'll give you feedback. Thanks

Comment: Should I replace the `@filename` and the `@filecontent` for its name and its content?

Comment: The names I have are variables is there any problem with it?

Comment: Ok, and the content I've a lot of variables, I write all of them there?

Comment: If it's just text...then u can append all of them into one and pass it.

Comment: Its not just text, I had to add something else for those variables to work

Comment: Ok, answer me there so we dont spam here